# HTML & CSS Timeline with relative positioned labels on top and on bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, timeline

I want to create something like the timeline using HTML and CSS:
[image]

But the only thing I am able to get is:
[image]

I can see at least two issues with my timeline:

- The labels relative X position are not the same as the relative X position of the bullets.
- Labels are not centered on each bullet.

You can the HTML and CSS that I used on the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/67562/

HTML:

```
<body style="background-color: #eee">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <br>
        <div class="list-grouplist-group" id="list">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <span class="progress-bar-label list-group-item-heading lead">Paul Mal</span>
            <div class="Timeline">
              <svg height="10" style="width:100%">
                        <line x1="0%" y1="5" x2="100%" y2="5" style="stroke:#AAAAAA;stroke-width:3" />
                        <circle cx="10%" cy="5" r="5" fill="#004165"/>
                        <line x1="10%" y1="5" x2="55%" y2="5" style="stroke:#004165;stroke-width:3" />
                        <circle cx="55%" cy="5" r="5" fill="#004165"/>
                     </svg>
              <span class="time" style="margin-left:10%">13:00 (6/May)</span>
              <span class="time2" style="margin-left:55%">19:27 (7/May)</span>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <span class="progress-bar-label list-group-item-heading lead">Jane Doe</span>
            <div class="Timeline">
              <svg height="10" style="width:100%">
                        <line x1="0%" y1="5" x2="100%" y2="5" style="stroke:#AAAAAA;stroke-width:3" />
                        <circle cx="90%" cy="5" r="5" fill="#004165"/>
                        <line x1="90%" y1="5" x2="100%" y2="5" style="stroke:#004165;stroke-width:3" />
                        <circle cx="100%" cy="5" r="5" fill="#004165"/>
                     </svg>
              <span class="time" style="margin-left:90%">13:00 (6/May)</span>
              <span class="time2" style="margin-left:100%">19:27 (7/May)</span>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <span class="progress-bar-label list-group-item-heading lead">John Doe</span>
            <div class="Timeline">
              <svg height="10" style="width:100%">
                        <line x1="0%" y1="5" x2="100%" y2="5" style="stroke:#AAAAAA;stroke-width:3" />
                        <circle cx="0%" cy="5" r="5" fill="#004165"/>
                        <line x1="0%" y1="5" x2="5%" y2="5" style="stroke:#004165;stroke-width:3" />
                        <circle cx="5%" cy="5" r="5" fill="#004165"/>
                     </svg>
              <span class="time" style="margin-left:0%">13:00 (6/May)</span>
              <span class="time2" style="margin-left:5%">19:27 (7/May)</span>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <span class="progress-bar-label list-group-item-heading lead">Thomas Phillips</span>
            <div class="Timeline">
              <svg height="10" style="width:100%">
                        <line x1="0%" y1="5" x2="100%" y2="5" style="stroke:#AAAAAA;stroke-width:3" />
                        <circle cx="70%" cy="5" r="5" fill="#004165"/>
                        <line x1="70%" y1="5" x2="71%" y2="5" style="stroke:#004165;stroke-width:3" />
                        <circle cx="71%" cy="5" r="5" fill="#004165"/>
                     </svg>
              <span class="time" style="margin-left:70%">13:00 (6/May)</span>
              <span class="time2" style="margin-left:71%">19:27 (7/May)</span>
            </div>
          </li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.Timeline {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 32px;
}

.time {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  color: #9E9E9E;
}

.time2 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-top: -12px;
  color: #9E9E9E;
}
```

Note 1: The positions are set dynamically after each call to a web service.
Note 2: I am using Bootstrap 3.

Can someone make this work?

Comment: adding `transform: translateX(-50%);` to both your `.time` classes [seems to help](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/67564/). But where are the inline margin-left values coming from (more important - how are they calculated)? That seems to be more of the issue. Can't you use `left` with `px` values instead since they are already absolute? Might be more accurate

Comment: @zgood GREAT! that is half of the job. Now I just need to align horizontally the labels with the bullets. Any ideas?